# Dataframe join tables & groupby not giving the expected output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get a table where it shows the pilot who has the fastest lap in each track. My result gives the fastest lap made by each pilot in the circuit, so for example in the example given it shows the fastest lap by pilot, but not the fastest record lap ever in the circuit.

I am going to provide what I have done so far and the result obtained.

```
#READ CSV FROM URL
results_df = pd.read_csv('data/results.csv')
races_df = pd.read_csv('data/races.csv')
drivers_df = pd.read_csv('data/drivers.csv')


fastest_lap = pd.merge(results_df, races_df, on='raceId', how='inner')
 
# Delete lap time that is \N
fastest_lap = fastest_lap[fastest_lap["fastestLapTime"] != '\\N']

driver_lap_time_by_circuit = pd.merge(fastest_lap, drivers_df, on="driverId", how="inner")

driver_lap_time_by_circuit = driver_lap_time_by_circuit[["circuitId","forename","fastestLapTime","name"]]

fastest_lap_by_circuit = driver_lap_time_by_circuit.sort_values("fastestLapTime",axis=1).groupby("circuitId")["name","forename","fastestLapTime"].first()

print(fastest_lap_by_circuit)
```

**Output**

| circuitId | name | forename | fastestLapTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Australian Grand Prix | Adrian | 1:28.687 |
|  |  |  | 1:28.943 |
|  |  |  | 1:30.710 |
|  |  |  | 1:31.526 |

**Expected output**

| circuitId | name | forename | fastestLapTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Australian Grand Prix | Adrian | 1:28.687 |
| 2 | Singapore GP | Hamilton | 1:43.045 |
| 3 | Italian GP | Alonso | 1:23.324 |
| 4 | Monaco | Alonso | 1:05.526 |

Answer (score 0):

Try first sorting by the fastest lap and the groupby circuit id and taking the first record -

`driver_lap_time_by_circuit.sort_values("fastestLapTime",axis=1).groupby("circuitId").first()["name","forename","fastestLapTime"]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That answer is giving me the following error: **raise KeyError(key)  KeyError: 'fastestLapTime'**

Comment: Hi Tom, did you had the chance to check the update?

Comment: @a.comino can you please provide a code example of the df?
It is hard for me to understand if it fails in the sort values part or in the column selection part.
Anyhow, try this - `driver_lap_time_by_circuit.sort_values("fastestLapTime",axis=1).groupby("circuitId")["name","forename","fastestLapTime"].first()`. If it works please let me know and I'll fix my answer.

Comment: The df is simply a read_csv. I have added the full code to the question.

Comment: Sorry, it is not helpful since I have no idea how the files look like. Please add the error you are getting using my code.